# What's the difference between Axes.text() and Axes.annotate() in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The document says

[Axes.text(self, x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=deprecated parameter, **kwargs)](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)

> Add text to the axes.
>
> Add the text s to the axes at location *x, y* in data coordinates.

[Axes.annotate(self, s, xy, *args, **kwargs)](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html)

> Annotate the point *xy* with text *s*.
>
> In the simplest form, the text is placed at *xy*.
>
> Optionally, the text can be displayed in another position *xytext*. An arrow pointing from the text to the annotated point *xy* can then be added by defining *arrowprops*.

The same is both `Axes.text()` and `Axes.annotate()` can add text to location x, y. The coordinate system can be changed using the *transform* parameter in `Axes.text()` while it is the *xycoords* parameter in `Axes.annotate()`.

The difference is `Axes.annotate()` can draw an arrow using the *arrowprops* parameter while `Axes.text()` cann't. Another difference I can see is the return value.

So I think `Axes.annotate()` is a superset of `Axes.text()`. Does it mean `Axes.text()` is useless? When should I use `Axes.text()` rather than `Axes.annotate()`?

Answer (score 13):

From the source code documentation:

```
class Annotation(Text, _AnnotationBase):
    """
    An `.Annotation` is a `.Text` that can refer to a specific position *xy*.
    Optionally an arrow pointing from the text to *xy* can be drawn.
```

Also, the Annotation subclasses Text. Here, Text is more general function to display text and annotate is the function display text associated to a point (or a location) in the plot. (especially, with the arrow-pointing support)